# Transforming for assumption of normality (normality of residuals)

Tags: multiple-regression, normality-assumption

My model has a violation of normality assumption so the residuals are not normally distributed. I have tried log transformation and Box-Cox, but nothing worked. Any suggestion?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You ask for "any suggestions", but for what? What is your goal?

Comment: @frant, I wonder if I should address the violation of this assumption(there is debate over its importance for the large sample size - mine is 124). If need to transform, what else transformation to use other than log and box-cox?

Comment: 1. The big issue with transformation is that you were previously assuming a linear relationship in E{Y|X=x) - if that was true before, it won't be the case after transformation of $Y$. Similarly if your assumption of homoskedasticity was correct before transformation, it won't be after transformation of $Y$. These are fundamental issues. $\:$ 2. Your residuals are light tailed and perhaps mildly left skew, log transformation wouldn't help. What's your response variable measuring?

Comment: You would be better off to ask a question about your data and modeling problem. Describe your data, your goal, hat you have done,  .....